# Mysql.Data.MysqlClient.MysqlConnectAttr threw an Exception

Tags: mysql, vb.net, visual-studio, xampp

Hi all I'm having trouble with regards to opening my connection on my mysql database on xampp. I'm not quite sure about the issue here. But please do correct me if I'm wrong, is there a problem with my connectionstring script or does Visual Studio 2019 handle it differently now compared to it's previous versions. I've tried removing the "con.Open()" line. but the problem with this is I can't seem to even be able to insert some data into my databse without the "con.Open()" line

here's the code by the way.

```
Module Module1
    Public con As New MySqlConnection
    Public cmd As New MySqlCommand

    Sub openCon()
        con.ConnectionString = "server=localhost; username=admin; password=; database=db_tutorial"
        con.Open()
    End Sub
End Module
```

here's an image of the error by the way.

[image: mysql xamppp error]

Comment: The error message is telling you what's wrong. Did you read it? It's telling you that a required assembly is missing. Is this, by any chance, a .NET Core project (.NET 5.0 is .NET Core) and you have failed to add a required package?

Comment: If it is .NET Core, did you intend it to be? If you want to target .NET Framework rather than .NET Core then you have to create a project that targets .NET Framework in the first place.

Comment: I chose .NET 5.0 for this.

Comment: I see, so I would have to install assembly then.

Comment: When projects target .NET Core, you generally need to add required libraries as NuGet packages. If you added Connector/Net as a NuGet package then it should normally add all its dependencies automatically. If it didn't for some reason, you can add them yourself.